# How to count weekday usage in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

**Dataset**

```
                  starttime   User Type
0         7/1/2015 00:00:03  Subscriber
1         7/1/2015 00:00:06  Subscriber
2         7/1/2015 00:00:17  Subscriber
3         7/1/2015 00:00:23  Subscriber
4         7/1/2015 00:00:44  Subscriber
5         7/1/2015 00:01:00  Subscriber
6         7/1/2015 00:01:03  Subscriber
7         7/1/2015 00:01:06  Subscriber
8         7/1/2015 00:01:25    Customer
9         7/1/2015 00:01:41  Subscriber
10        7/1/2015 00:01:50    Customer
11        7/1/2015 00:01:58  Subscriber
12        7/1/2015 00:02:06  Subscriber
13        7/1/2015 00:02:07  Subscriber
14        7/1/2015 00:02:26  Subscriber
15        7/1/2015 00:02:26  Subscriber
16        7/1/2015 00:02:35  Subscriber
17        7/1/2015 00:02:43    Customer
18        7/1/2015 00:02:47    Customer
19        7/1/2015 00:02:47  Subscriber
20        7/1/2015 00:03:05  Subscriber
21        7/1/2015 00:03:16    Customer
22        7/1/2015 00:03:27  Subscriber
23        7/1/2015 00:03:34  Subscriber
24        7/1/2015 00:03:48  Subscriber
25        7/1/2015 00:03:56  Subscriber
26        7/1/2015 00:03:57  Subscriber
27        7/1/2015 00:03:58    Customer
28        7/1/2015 00:04:03  Subscriber
29        7/1/2015 00:04:17  Subscriber
...                     ...         ...
1085646  7/31/2015 23:57:25  Subscriber
1085647  7/31/2015 23:57:29    Customer
1085648  7/31/2015 23:57:32  Subscriber
1085649  7/31/2015 23:57:33  Subscriber
1085650  7/31/2015 23:57:44  Subscriber
1085651  7/31/2015 23:57:54  Subscriber
1085652  7/31/2015 23:58:03  Subscriber
1085653  7/31/2015 23:58:08  Subscriber
1085654  7/31/2015 23:58:12    Customer
1085655  7/31/2015 23:58:15  Subscriber
1085656  7/31/2015 23:58:18    Customer
1085657  7/31/2015 23:58:24  Subscriber
1085658  7/31/2015 23:58:27  Subscriber
1085659  7/31/2015 23:58:42  Subscriber
1085660  7/31/2015 23:58:43  Subscriber
1085661  7/31/2015 23:58:51    Customer
1085662  7/31/2015 23:58:53  Subscriber
1085663  7/31/2015 23:58:58  Subscriber
1085664  7/31/2015 23:59:04  Subscriber
1085665  7/31/2015 23:59:10  Subscriber
1085666  7/31/2015 23:59:24  Subscriber
1085667  7/31/2015 23:59:23    Customer
1085668  7/31/2015 23:59:24  Subscriber
1085669  7/31/2015 23:59:24  Subscriber
1085670  7/31/2015 23:59:38  Subscriber
1085671  7/31/2015 23:59:40  Subscriber
1085672  7/31/2015 23:59:41  Subscriber
1085673  7/31/2015 23:59:42    Customer
1085674  7/31/2015 23:59:56  Subscriber
1085675  7/31/2015 23:59:59  Subscriber
```

**My Question**

Create a pandas DataFrame with the number of rides by User Type for each day of the week. Use starttime to determine the rides week day. Your

**The output should be similar to the one show below, but data values will vary.**

```
 User 
  Type
  Week  Customer Subscriber
  Day   

    0   1679    53569
    1   1222    59323
    2   1765    74118
    3   1981    85190
    4   5403    99728
    5   7004    60580
    6   5489    52427
```

**My Code**

```
def a7(rides):
    rides['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(rides['starttime'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    g = rides.groupby(rides.starttime.dt.dayofweek)['User Type']
    print g
```

but **output is**

```
<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x7feb970ae510>
```

Also, I want to plot a graph which shows the weekday usage pattern by user type. Include a plot line for All weekday rides.

**Graph should be like below:**

[image: plt-day_of_week]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need some aggregate function like [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html).

Also for shorcuts of days use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) (http://strftime.org/) and for correct sorting use [`sorted categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
cats = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']
days = pd.Categorical(rides.starttime.dt.strftime('%a'), categories=cats, ordered=True)

df = rides.groupby([days, 'User Type'])
          .size()
          .unstack(fill_value=0)
          .assign(All=lambda x: x.sum(1))
print (df)
User Type  Customer  Subscriber  All
starttime                           
Friday            6          24   30
Wednesday         6          24   30
```

Another alternative with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(days, rides['User Type']) \
       .assign(All=lambda x: x.sum(1))

print (df)
User Type  Customer  Subscriber  All
row_0                               
Mon               0           0    0
Tue               0           0    0
Wed               6          24   30
Thu               0           0    0
Fri               6          24   30
Sat               0           0    0
Sun               0           0    0
```

Last [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and set labels:

```
ax = df.plot()
ax.set_ylabel('Daily Rides by User Types')
ax.set_xlabel('Days of the Week')
ax.set_title('Number of Rides by User Types and Week Day')
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Great answer!  If you wanted to, you could categorize the days to plot them in order.  Good night.

Comment: Thanks, @jezrael for a reply. I got Output as I want but I didn't get any plot if I run the code.

Answer (score 0):

#### Make dataframe

```
category = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=1000)
timestamp= np.sort(np.random.randint(1435676400, 1438354800, size=1000))

df = pd.DataFrame({'starttime': timestamp, 'User Type': category})
df['User Type'] = df['User Type'].apply(lambda i: 'Subscriber' if i else 'Customer')
df['starttime'] = df['starttime'].apply(pd.Timestamp.fromtimestamp)
```

#### Add weekday column

```
df['weekday'] = df['starttime'].apply(lambda i: i.weekday())
```

#### Make summary with groupby

```
summary = df.groupby(['weekday', 'User Type']).count().unstack()['starttime']
print(summary)

User Type  Customer  Subscriber
weekday                        
0                60          70
1                68          66
2                93          77
3                76          77
4                89          74
5                56          56
6                70          68
```

#### Plot

```
summary.plot()
```

[image]